# Is it possible to buy commodity ETFs (e.g. silver) through Questrade?

Tags: canada, etf, broker, commodities, questrade

Is there a way to buy a silver ETF through Questrade? Or do they offer only mutual funds?

Answer (score 3):

[Questrade](http://questrade.com/) is a Canada based broker offering US stock exchange transactions as well. It says this right on their homepage. ETFs are traded like stocks, so the answer is yes. 
Why did you think they only offered funds?